# How does JavaScript identify unquoted plain expression as RegExp Object?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, mozilla, rhino

Considering the **JavaScript** `RegExp` and its declaration process you may declare a regular expression in **JavaScript** on the fly

```
var exp_blood = /^[A|a|B|b|AB|ab|O|o]{1,2}[+-]{1}$/;
```

or initialize it with its constructor `RegExp`

```
var exp_blood = new RegExp("/^[A|a|B|b|AB|ab|O|o]{1,2}[+-]{1}$/");
```

Considering this scenario I would like to build an object on the fly without initializing any constructor explicitly or with a finite/unique expression. I would like to declare an object without using its Constructor named HL7V2. I could create an object with its Constructor. For example:

```
var hl7 = new HL7V2("MSH|^~\&|SENDERAPP|SENDERFAC|COVCDR|COVCDR|20130212221503||ORU^R01|1676326503009050|P|2.6");
```

But my goal is to instantiate it on the fly like `RegExp` in **JavaScript**

```
var hl7 = MSH|^~\&|SENDERAPP|SENDERFAC|COVCDR|COVCDR|20130212221503||ORU^R01|1676326503009050|P|2.6;
```

Is it possible or any suggestion?

Comment: `var exp_blood = /(?:[abo]|ab){1,2}[+-]$/i;`

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do... What is that object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RegExp syntax is one of a few [literal syntaxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) built in to the language which allow you to create objects of a certain type using a special syntax (other types that can be built using literal syntaxes include [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals)).

These syntaxes are features of the language, and you can't add new ones for your own types.

It is possible to create objects using the [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), but it sounds like you want to create a specific type of object, which this won't help you with - I don't think what you want to do is possible.